# open panel/modal in route - Ember.JS

Tags: ember.js, panel, ember-router

I have created now a simple authentication with this tutorial:

http://www.embercasts.com/episodes/client-side-authentication-part-1

So i have created the AuthenticatedRoute, and all the other routes, that need a logged in user, are extending the AuthenticatedRoute.

And in the beforeModel, i check if the user is logged in. And if he's not logged in, i call: `this.transitionTo("login")`.

My question is now: How could i put the whole login form in a Panel?
My idea was to open the panel in the AuthenticatedRoute -> beforeModel event, and if the login was successful, do retry the redirect.

My idea, but i dont know how to implement it.

```
App.AuthenticatedRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  beforeModel: function(transition) {
    if (!App.get("currentUser")) {
      transition.abort(); // loading spinner doesn't disappears if i call this??
      this.showLogin(transition);
    }
  },

  showLogin: function(transition) {
    var loginController = this.controllerFor("login");
    loginController.set("attemptedTransition", transition);

    // OPEN PANEL, if the panel gets closed, do nothing. If login successfull, redirect to attemptedTransition and hide the panel.
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bottom of [this page](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/preventing-and-retrying-transitions/) tells how to persist a transition and retry it later.

[This page](http://hawkins.io/2013/06/ember-and-bootstrap-modals/) tells how to setup a modal, although in recent versions of ember you want to call `disconnectOutlet` rather than rendering an empty template into the modal outlet.